# m_installedLocation = Package::Current().InstalledLocation(); function does not work

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

```
 winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFolder  m_installedLocation{ nullptr };
 m_installedLocation = Package::Current().InstalledLocation();
```

Because of this code, my exe crashes. I am new to UWP projects. I downloaded some code from internet but it did not work because of these lines. I did some research on the internet and I guess it's a security related issue but I couldn't find an alternative function. What can i use instead of Package::Current().InstalledLocation()? Also the return value must be winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFolder

Comment: The executable doesn't crash. It gets terminated due to an unhandled exception. What's the specific exception code you get?

Comment: @IInspectable When i debug it, i get this: At point 0x00007FFA16F04ED9, exception occurred on direct2d.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_error. Memory location: 0x000000A5644FF5F0.

Comment: There's an `HRESULT` wrapped inside the C++ exception. That's the important piece of information. What is it?

Comment: @IInspectable I am sorry, I don't know how to find that information. As I said, I am new at this.

Comment: Does `Package::Current()` give a valid value?